# Doctrine2: OneToOne invalid field type

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have strange issue with simple tree structure..

```
class CourseCategory {
  /** @Id @Column(name="Id", type="integer", unique=true) 
   *  @GeneratedValue
   */
  private $id = null;

  /** @Column(name="Name", length=2000) */
  private $name;

  /**
   * @OneToOne(targetEntity="CourseCategory")
   * @JoinColumn(name="ParentId", referencedColumnName="Id", nullable=true)
   **/
  private $parent;

  /** @Column(name="Slug", length=255) */
  private $slug;

  /** @Column(name="PageTitle", length=2000) */
  private $pageTitle;

  /** @Column(name="Order", type="integer") */
  private $order;

  public function __construct($name, $parent, $slug, $pageTitle, $order) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->parent = $parent;
    $this->slug = $slug;
    $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;
    $this->order = $order;
  }
}
```

Adding new category:

```
$category = new CourseCategory($name, $parentCategory, $slug, $pageTitle, 
        $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM Entity\CourseCategory c')->getSingleScalarResult() + 1);
      $em->persist($category);
      $em->flush();
```

This code fails with `Syntax error or access violation: 1064` exception. Somehow it tries to add string into ParentId field:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order, ParentId) VALUES ('123', '123', '123', 47, '1')
```

Do somebody know why it happens? Thank you

Comment: can you var_dump($parent) or Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($parent) and see the data type of $id in it. I am guessing the way the $parent is initialized might be causing something. I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew about this feature.